# jQuery is not firing backend method in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am firing `Backend` method of asp.net using `jQuery`. I have set everything perfectly as much i knew. But still don't know what is the wrong.
Please help me to solve this issue.
**My Code :**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update" />

var jquery = $.noConflict();
jquery(document).ready(function() {
jquery("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").click(function() {
                if(jquery("#form1").valid()) {

                    jquery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Page.aspx/UpdateData",
                        data: jquery("#form1").serialize(),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                        },
                        error: function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

**Backend method :**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string UpdateData(string get_param)
{
     // Code...
}
```

I also tried to check by using `BeakPoint` but it is not going in code behind. Even, I can't see any error.

Comment: where did you post string get_param via ajax?

Comment: @ArunPrasanth, I am handling it in code behind.

Comment: Try to remove contentType.

Comment: If you want to post any string values to your code behind then you should post that via ajax data : as same name and same type, Try to remove parameter from your codebehind function  and post empty data  from ajax and then try. I think then your function will hit. If it hits then you can ensure that problem is in your data section post

Answer (score 1):

I removed content type. As you are using formSerialize. It will form data like key=value&key1=value1 and it is not json format so.

note: Make sure you have form with id form1 present.

```
jquery(document).ready(function() {
jquery("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").click(function() {
                if(jquery("#form1").valid()) {

                    jquery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Page.aspx/UpdateData",
                        data: '{ "get_param" :"' +  $('form').serialize() + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                           
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                        },
                        error: function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove contentType from ajax request anf get dataa

```
public static string UpdateData(string get_param)
    string get_params= HttpContext.Current.Request["get_param"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myName
    {
        get { return "Hello"; }
    }
}
```

In your aspx.cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object MyMethod()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

And in your ASPX page:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "somepage.aspx/MyMethod",
            data: {},
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                    alert(data.d.myName);
                else
                    alert(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert(reponse);
            }
        });
```

Comment: is your function getting called ? have you tried putting an alert ?

Comment: still same issue. I have tried many syntax. It is not going in back end when i checked using breakpoint. What should i check now ?

Comment: I checked and it was working. try creating a fresh demo project and  do a hello world example.

Comment: My page is inside another main `.aspx`. It is like iframe. So, can it create problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to send json data, convert your data to json format.

var jquery = $.noConflict();
jquery(document).ready(function() {
jquery("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").click(function() {
            if(jquery("#form1").valid()) {

                jquery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Page.aspx/UpdateData",
                    data:  JSON.stringify({ get_param:jquery("#form1").serialize() }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because of `asp.net button`. It was refreshing page after validation completion. So, I used `preventDefault` after button click in `jquery` and it has solved my issue.

**Check my code :**

```
function pageLoad() { 
      jquery('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            if(jquery("#form1").valid()) {
                  e.preventDefault(); // this line was imp

                  // Ajax call...
      });
}
```